Fitting an affine subspace to points.
Suppose I am given $N$ points $x_1,...,x_N$ in a finite-dimensional real inner product space $V$ of dimension $n$ and suppose I am given an integer $0 < k < n$.  For concreteness, maybe we will just take $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual dot product.  Let's say I want to find a description of an affine subspace $E$ (say a system of linear equations or a basis for the subspace moved to go through the origin together with an offset vector) such that the sum of the distances of the points $x_i$ to $E$ is minimized.
I am sure many people have run into this optimization problem before.  Does such a subspace $E$ (which I presume generically is unique) have a name?
Is there an efficient way to do this (and if not, is there an efficient approximation?)?

Did you Google it? What did you find?

@Sprotte This is one way to interpret the results of principal component analysis. The affine subspace $E$ is just the span of the first $k$ principal components, recentered at the mean of the data.

@Sprotte The description of affine subspace that you get is an orthonormal basis for the parallel linear subspace. You can always take the mean of the data as the base point.

@BenGrossmann Thank you Ben!  PCA it is!
